How to write a dependent package that should export a file outside the vendor directory?
I am writing a package where there is a certain file that needs to be moved outside the vendor directory so that users can edit this file.
I tried to write it like this:
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "php -r \"file_put_contents('../../../dictionary.php', '......');\""
    ]
}

However, from the documentation I understood that calling scripts from dependent packages is prohibited:

Note: Only scripts defined in the root package's composer.json are executed. If a dependency of the root package specifies its own scripts, Composer does not execute those additional scripts

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

This question is similar to: Composer run-script of nested packages. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Are you maybe using any framework that could help? For example, Symfony's Flex contains a solution for this, named Recipes
